# How to verify selector NOT present in cucumberjs / puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, assert, puppeteer, cucumberjs

I'm trying to verify selector NOT present in cucumberjs / puppeteer.  How do you use the throws assertion using cucumber-assert?

I'm working on test automation to support testing an ember front-end application.  I'm using cucumberjs, puppeteerjs, and cucumber-assert.

I've used the following before:

```
if (await page.waitForSelector('[data-test-text-title-refunded-widget-console="true"]')) {
            let textContentOfElement = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.querySelector('[data-test-text-title-refunded-widget-console="true"]').textContent);
            return assert.equal(textContentOfElement, widgetTitle, `title with text ${  widgetTitle  } is not present`);
        }
```

which works when I'm verifying the an element exists and the text is correct.
For my current assert, I was using the following throws assert from the cucumber-assert npm package:

```
assert.throws(someFunctionThatThrows).then(callback);
```

I'm not sure how to handle the callback function - I have the following so far.

```
const assert = require('cucumber-assert');

return assert.throws(await page.waitForSelector('[data-test-text-title- import-payment-file-widget-console="true"]'))
                .then(function(err) {

            });
```

should I return a fail in the callback?

*** UPDATE ***
I believe I found a different approach to solve my issue.   Here it is shoudl anyone else have the same issue in the future.

```
    if (await page.$('[data-test-text-title-import-payment-file-widget-console="true"]', { timeout: settings._30000 }) === null) {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
    return Promise.reject('Error: The widget is present');
```

Comment: Hmmm.....I just found the expect-puppeteer npm module.  Perhaps this might work better for me.

Comment: I don't think expect-puppeteer npm module will satisfy my verification need.

Answer (score 5):

What I do for something like this is to create a method as follows:

```
const isElementVisible = async (page, cssSelector) => {
  let visible = true;
  await page.waitForSelector(cssSelector, { visible: true, timeout: 2000 })
  .catch(() => {
    visible = false;
  });
  return visible;
};

// Invoke it as follows
const isVisible = await isElementVisible(page, elementCssSelector);
console.log(isVisible); // Outputs true or false
```

Just some pointers about how this method works:

- I've deliberately set the `timeout` to `2000` since, if a selector is not visible you don't want your code to be waiting around for the default `30000`  (in most cases). Maybe you want to increase / decrease this `timeout` setting as you see fit for your test script.
- You need that `catch` block simply because you're actually expecting the element to not be visible. When the timeout occurs, your test script will trigger an exception as `puppeteer`  thinks there's an error. You don't want this to kill your test script. Instead the `catch` block will catch that exception and instead set `visible` to `false`, which is then returned cleanly.

Hopefully this helps you out!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ExpectedConditions library. StalenessOf is the method you will want use. See here how to use it https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.stalenessOf